# Do we need to declare JPA tranasaction mange programatically in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to call a Oracle DB and fetch a table data and Insert the data.I have Spring Boot 1.2.4 application with Spring Data JPA.Spring Boot will inject LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and Datasource beans by default provided necessary properties are provided in application.properties.Now I want to implement Tranaction Mangament. My question is Do I need to define a JPATransactionManage bean declaratively or this will also injected by Spring Boot by default.If its injected by default which annotation will inject it in Spring Boot is there any documentation which explains this in Spring Boot terms.

Answer (score 0):

Because such infrastructure is now available and you have no dedicated configuration, a DataSourceTransactionManager will also be created for you: this is the component that intercepts the @Transactional annotated method

Reference : https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/